# SQL Server service not automatically starting (logon failure)

Tags: sql-server, authentication, service, sql-server-2012

I just installed SQL Server 2012 on a machine. To run "SQL Server" as well as "SQL Server Agent" service I have created a domain account called SQLADMIN. This account is a service account and has no other rights like logon locally or local administrator.

When the machine restarts, "SQL Server" service doesn't start automatically. When I click Start then it says "Logon Failure". Now if I simply enter the password again under tab "Log On" and then start service then it starts. Why doesn't it start automatically?

**EDIT**
This is not the first time it is happening. I have another SQL Server machine and it shows same behaviour. Could it be because of some domain policy? I have installed this SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: does your Windows event log give your more info ?

Comment: It says "The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service failed to start due to the following error: The service did nit start due to a logon failure."

Comment: look at this maybe http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cb9cbc5c-b2f9-4656-97e9-f69542c0b10f/an-error-1069-the-service-did-not-start-due-to-logon-failure-occurred-while-performing-this?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Answer (score -3, accepted):

II talked to domain administrator and he did something in the AD which fixed the issue. Looks like it was related to some AD policy.

Comment: Well that's really helpful.  He *did something*?  Fantastic!!

Comment: And that thing is related to SOME AD policy, be careful :p